# Http post with anti-forgery, token, cookie and parameters

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make a post from within my Android app to the asp.net mvc4 website 
but the result of the post is an error page which contains [HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.]

MVC view

```
@model PoliticiOnline.Models.RegisterModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Registreer";
}

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/registreer.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="form">

<div id="avatar">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/avatarempty.png" alt="avatar" height="120" width="120">   <br />
    <input class="button" title="avatar" name="avatarbrowse" id="avatarbrowse" value="Blader" type="file">
</div>

<fieldset>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <p class="contact">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                </p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="contact">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                </p>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="contact">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                </p>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </li>

        <li>
            <p class="contact">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                </p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="contact">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GeboorteDatum)
                </p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GeboorteDatum)
        </li>

        <li>
            <p class="contact">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Naam)
                </p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Naam)
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="contact">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Voornaam)
                </p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Voornaam)
        </li>

        <li>
            <p class="contact">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Postcode)
                </p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Postcode)
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="contact">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Geslacht)
                </p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Geslacht)
        </li>

        <li>
            <p class="contact">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Taal)
                </p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Taal)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input class="button" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="8" value="Registreer!" type="submit">
    <div id="policy">
        Als je op Registreer klikt bevestig je dat je onze
        <br />
        <a href="@Url.Action("Algvoorw", "Account")" id="voorw" class="">Algemene voorwaarden</a>, en onze <a href="@Url.Action("Privacy", "Account")" id="privacy" class="">Privacy Policy</a>,
        <br />
        en onze  <a href="@Url.Action("GedragsCode", "Shared")" id="gedr" class="">Gedragscode</a>
        inclusief ons gebruik van<br />
        cookies, aanvaardt.
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                if (!WebSecurity.UserExists(model.UserName)) 
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Email = model.Email, GeboorteDatum = model.GeboorteDatum, Naam = model.Naam, Voornaam = model.Voornaam, Postcode = model.Postcode, Geslacht = Geslacht.MAN, Taal = Taal.NL, AccountType = AccountType.BURGER, Discriminator = "Burger" });
                if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Burger")) Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Burger");

                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Android code

```
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
 // Do request
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.134.216.25:8011/Account/Register");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //get cookie
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie("10.134.216.25:8011");

        Log.e("Politici", "The cookie is: " + cookie);

        //add cookie to cookiestore
        BasicClientCookie ckie = new BasicClientCookie("__RequestVerificationToken", cookie.replace("__RequestVerificationToken=",""));
        ckie.setPath("http://10.134.216.25:8011/Account/Register");
        ckie.setDomain("http://10.134.216.25:8011");
        CookieStore store = httpclient.getCookieStore();
        store.addCookie(ckie);


        for(Cookie cokie : store.getCookies()){
            Log.e("Politici", cokie.toString());
        }
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__RequestVerificationToken",token));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname","as400"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname","samplecode"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        Log.e("Politici", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.e("Politici", resEntity.getContentLength() + "");
            Log.e("Politici", resEntity.isChunked() + "");

            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            Log.e("Politici", responseBody);
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return "";
}
```

It is an AsyncTask and the token parameter is the value I get from requesting the source page e.g

`<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="p0-uI4yeEJFyJP8GW3mwTR_b031K-ZqksW8E-hCEaHJi_iGrGJrhmE6Xid1bARGno32KAljv7AHigae8f7S2wGb2m0M1UT_7E7niQ85r0S81" />`

This is what a post looks like on the page.

```
POST /Account/Register HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2334
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 334
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:2334
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:2334/Account/Register
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=XN8W3-H0-btSjGJzEpaW4t5g1tRwNJC-R3CcI3_RpwVDXTRMzW20sR3_nTh7guTC7-nTbPHfDl7uFnTuPOoSGevnENzhUDPbbvMnYBixYRQ1

__RequestVerificationToken=_pnAR4aE3dpcpHt3zGqYpYf0YX3VC7a49mk2UvT-lTJt8_nFGVGHzpOY2LD0J71agcivfxxP2oRTwEjyi3Q5Ty_Y59ZsnX1QEbzsMPERkRo1

&UserName=username
&Password=password
&ConfirmPassword=password
&Email=email%40email.com
&GeboorteDatum=dateofbirth
&Naam=surname
&Voornaam=firstname
&Postcode=2000
&Geslacht=Man
&Taal=NL
&submit=Registreer%21
```

So the only problem is making the post from Android which messes up with the cookie and or token I think. What am I doing wrong?

SOLVED: 
Working code

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
// Do request
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.134.216.25:8011/Account/Register");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        //get cookie
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie("10.134.216.25:8011");

        //add cookie to header
        httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__RequestVerificationToken",token));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname","as400"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname","samplecode"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        Log.e("Politici", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.e("Politici", resEntity.getContentLength() + "");
            Log.e("Politici", resEntity.isChunked() + "");

            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            Log.e("Politici", responseBody);
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/) site `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` checks for all of the following:

1. That the request has a cookie called "__RequestVerificationToken".
2. That the request has a form NameValuePair with the name "__RequestVerificationToken".
3. That the value of the values of 1 and 2 are equal.

Below is the HTTP Post request made from the register page in a brand new MVC project, which uses `AntiForgeryToken`.

```
POST http://localhost:32887/Account/Register HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:32887
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 190
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:32887
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:32887/Account/Register
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=Y67NY_sxp8tun8hRwfx0_RSG0d0NkJtCr-GbUOFpbRROQ-4kJcJVnIeQEbhiGZP5NCRDutO_JbeuRKp6GaFpe5o6fq8r_Wo8WbcBXPTWot41

__RequestVerificationToken=QpkYjvwoHSKR7eeto0iKigsoI7B01q_mvF99fYih39XMTSptYJc97Xpgi4Qha7pUcbVverpr_nW7RRP4_-7yOpPE0OB7j6_M0LjJlk94VcE1&UserName=asdfgh&Password=asdfgh&ConfirmPassword=asdfgh
```

---

I haven't tried running your code, but I can see two issues:

First, in your code I can't see where you are includes the NameValuePair with a name "__RequestVerificationToken" to satisfy check 2.

Second, in my HTTP request there isn't a "__RequestVerificationToken" HTTP header. I don't think you need it.

Comment: Adrian, thanks for the help, I changed my code to your findings (new code is in the question) but I still get a 500 error page which sais <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>The required anti-forgery cookie &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present.</title>

Comment: I got it working by manually adding the cookie to the post header. 
Included working code in original question.